# Nginx rewrite configuration for CodeIgniter apps in main CodeIgniter app's subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx

*Moving from Apache to a new Nginx server I can't figure out this new rewrite code...*

I have a site that has main CodeIgniter app, let's say **www.codeigniterapp.com**.

Then I have separate CodeIgniter apps like this **www.codeigniterapp.com/random-directory/app2** etc.

Main CodeIgniter app works fine, but apps in the subdirectory will fail when loading anything else than the base url.

For example **www.codeigniterapp.com/random-directory/app2** works, but **www.codeigniterapp.com/random-directory/app2/some-action-here** will print out an 404 error.
I need some-action-here to be sent to index.php.
It works like this:
**www.codeigniterapp.com/random-directory/app2/index.php?/some-action-here**

So I need help in creating the Nginx rewrite code.
Old apache .htaccess in app2 -directory was like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /random-directory/app2/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Now I'm using a Nginx (Code Igniter optimized) vhost configuration like this:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name codeigniterapp.com  www.codeigniterapp.com;

    root /var/www/codeigniterapp.com;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
    add_header X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "NOSNIFF";

    autoindex off;
    index maintenance.html index.php index.html index.htm; 

    # Hide files that begin with a "."
    location ~ /\. {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        return 404;
    }

    # Images and text files are served normally, while everything else is downloaded.
    # PHP will not execute!
    location /uploads {
        types {
            image/gif       gif;
            image/jpeg      jpeg jpg;
            image/png       png;
            text/plain      txt;
            application/pdf pdf;
        }
        default_type    application/octet-stream;
        location ~ \.php$
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    # Codeigniter; rewrite default controller and "/index.php" back to root domain.
    if ($request_uri ~* ^(/welcome(/index)?|/index(.php)?)/?$) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ / permanent;
    }

    # Codeigniter; rewrite "controller/index" back to root "controller".
    if ($request_uri ~* index/?$) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/index/?$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # Codeigniter; remove trailing slashes.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # Main location block. If the file or folder exists, display it, otherwise fallback
    # to the site location block.
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @site;
    }

    # Codeigniter; pass the current request to the index.php file for Codeigniter to handle.
    location @site {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    }

    # Proxy PHP files to PHP-FPM.
    # If the file doesn't exist then throw a 404 (defined below).
    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param CI_ENV production;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    }

    # Pass not-found errors back to Codeigniter to handle.
    error_page 404 /index.php;

    # Cache static files. Don't bother logging them.
    location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|xml)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires 30d;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved! I added the following to my vhost configuration

```
location /random-directory/app2/ {
    if ($request_uri ~ "^system.*"){
        rewrite ^/random-directory/app2/(.*)$ /random-directory/app2/index.php?/$1 last;
    }
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^/random-directory/app2/(.*)$ /random-directory/app2/index.php?/$1 last;
    }
}
```